# How can awk utility process multi-format timestamps in this command

Tags: awk

I am extracting content from log files, based on time ranges, i.e. between two timestamps.

This is what I use to extract filtered content:

```
awk --assign start='2020-09-13T00:25:15' --assign end='2020-09-13T00:25:19' 
'/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} / { inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end } inrange' 
< path/to/my/file
```

It works just great if timestamps in a log file are in that format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss".
However, different log files have various formats.
So I need to run a different command for the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" for example.
It would be:

```
awk --assign start='2020-09-13 00:25:15' --assign end='2020-09-13 00:25:19' 
'/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} / { inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end } inrange' 
< path/to/my/file
```

How do I unify my command to adapt to a format like "yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm:ss" where a dot is any character like a regular expression?

I tried something like

```
awk --assign start='2020-09-13/./00:25:15' --assign end='2020-09-13/./00:25:19' 
'/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} / { inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end } inrange' 
< path/to/my/file
```

It didn't work.

Here is a sample data for a test:

```
2020-09-13T00:25:14.968+0300: line1
2020-09-13T00:25:14.969+0300: line2
2020-09-13T00:25:16.000+0300: line3
2020-09-13T00:25:16.001+0300: line4
2020-09-13T00:25:16.200+0300: line5
NullPointerException          line6
caused by:                    line7
some code at some line.       line8
this is without timestamps    line9
2020-09-13T00:25:18.000+0300: line10
2020-09-13T00:25:19.000+0300: line11
2020-09-13T00:25:20.000+0300: line12
2020-09-13T00:25:40.000+0300: line13
```

My command should extract lines in time interval from 2020-09-13 00:25:15 to 2020-09-13 00:25:19.

Expected output:

```
2020-09-13T00:25:16.000+0300: line3
2020-09-13T00:25:16.001+0300: line4
2020-09-13T00:25:16.200+0300: line5
NullPointerException          line6
caused by:                    line7
some code at some line.       line8
this is without timestamps    line9
2020-09-13T00:25:18.000+0300: line10
2020-09-13T00:25:19.000+0300: line11
```

Now imagine same log data with timestamp 2020-09-13 00:25:16.000+0300
or 2020-09-13t00:25:16.000+0300, - it still has to produce same expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to allow for patterns in the input variables. Maybe update the code to normalize the information in the variables.

```
awk -v start='2020-09-13T00:25:15' -v end='2020-09-13T00:25:19' \
'!(FILENAME in known) && /^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}T/ {
  if (start !~ /T/) sub(" ", "T", start)
  if (end !~ /T/) sub(" ", "T", end)
  known[FILENAME] = "T" }
!(FILENAME in known) && /^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2} / {
  if (start ~ /T/) sub("T", " ", start)
  if (end ~ /T/) sub("T", " ", end)
  known[FILENAME] = " " }
/^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}[ T]/ { inrange = $0 >= start && $0 <= end} inrange' path/to/my/file
```

The code is slightly bulky and repetitive but it should be reasonably fast and obvious what's going on here. If the format in the variable does not agree with what's in this file, change the variable. Do this first for `start` (convert to have a space instead of a `T` if that's what's in the file, and vice versa) and then for `end`. The `known` associative array is updated to mark the current file (whose name is in `FILENAME`) as already checked, to avoid repeatedly performing the same check on every subsequent line in the file.  This obviously assumes that the format within a file is consistent.

(Notice also how I refactored the final line slightly. Your original attempt would not allow a `T` after the date, so it would probably not actually work with your first example. I switched to `-v` in preference over `--assign` since the latter is not portable.)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the char between the date and time from the input to a blank or `T` (or whatever it is you want to use in the beginning and ending timestamps you set on the command line) before comparing it to those range delimiters:

```
awk -v beg='2020-09-13 00:25:15' -v end='2020-09-13 00:25:19' '
    match($0,/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/) {
        cur = substr($0,1,RLENGTH) " " substr($0,RLENGTH+2,8)
        inrange = (beg <= cur && cur <= end)
    }
    inrange
' file
2020-09-13T00:25:16.000+0300: line3
2020-09-13T00:25:16.001+0300: line4
2020-09-13T00:25:16.200+0300: line5
NullPointerException          line6
caused by:                    line7
some code at some line.       line8
this is without timestamps    line9
2020-09-13T00:25:18.000+0300: line10
```

Comment: Fails for timestamp with 'T' like 2020-09-13T00:25:15.

Comment: Also, it should be cur < end, because otherwise it grabs everything between 2020-09-13 00:25:19 and 2020-09-13 00:25:19.999. Also your command runs 9.4 sec versus 2.4 sec from provided solution.
But thanks anyway.

Comment: @landsreyk no, it doesn't fail for any timestamp such as you've described so if something didn't work for you then you're doing something different that I have in my code (maybe your setting beg or end to a timestamp with a T in the middle instead of a blank?), it uses `<=` because your code used `<=` so if that's not really what you want then change it, the code in the accepted answer won't work if the char in the middle is `t` instead of `T` (one of the cases you said you have), It makes sense that my answer would be a bit slower.